# How to change order of elements in a row bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

There is a row of images.

```
<div class="mainWrap">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/4.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, on a small screen it looks like:

```
1 2
3 4
```

But it needs to be displayed like this:

```
1 2
4 3
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

just give them all a col-sm-6 in two rows :-

```
<div class="mainWrap">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/2.png" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img/4.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="./img3.png" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```